# HTML position:relative

Tags: html, css, position

Given the following css

```
li.menuitem{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:20px;
display:inline;
```

I would expect each li to be positioned 20 pixels further left than it would be without position relative.

However, what happens is that as I change the value of left, **all**  if the menu items move together in relation to the left position.  In other words, the space between items does not change.

While there are other ways to achieve what I want, I am curious as to why both items move and the distance between then does not change.

Thanks,
-dmd-

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what `margin-left` is for.

Here's an illustration: if you and I are walking side-by-side and we both take 20 steps forward, you and I would still be side-by-side.

Similarly, `position: relative` doesn't take into account the new positioning of other `position: relative` elements around it. They all move relative to where they naturally are, and not relative to where other elements now are.

The [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for `position: relative` states:

> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).